# Issue with ng-model returns undefined when I select one of the item from ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an issue with the ng-model returning undefined. ILookupItem is a lookup object that has data I need this is where ng-options are taking values. Dropdown looks good but if I select item setter value is undefined. I'm not sure why it does this... when I don't select anything default is null which is what I expected but once I select item it returns undefined.

```js
export interface ILookupItem {
        contextFlags?: number;
        description: string;
        disabled: boolean;
        enumValue?: number;
        lookupFilter?: LookupFilterTypeEnum;
        orderValue: number;
        removed?: boolean;
        selected: boolean;
        stringValue: string;
        text: string;
        value: string;
    }

get deliveryType() {
    return this.deliveryType;
}

set deliveryType(deliveryMethod) {
    this.deliveryType = deliveryMethod;
}

get deliveryTypes() {
    return this.deliveryTypes;
}
```

```html
<workflow-field>
      <select ng-model="deliveryTypeCtrl.deliveryType"
              ng-options="deliveryTypes.enumValue as deliveryTypes.text for deliveryTypes in deliveryTypeCtrl.deliveryTypes">
          <option value=''>Select One</option>
      </select>
</workflow-field>
```

Comment: Are you using the former [AngularJS framework](https://angularjs.org) or the [Angular v2+ framework](https://angular.io)?

Comment: angularjs @Edric

Comment: Your code appears to be in TypeScript, but you have used the [tag:javascript] and [tag:angularjs] tags.

Comment: I added typescript. Thanks for pointing out